# Adding Javascript to Custom widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-custom-field

This question is related to

[Django: Best Way to Add Javascript to Custom Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226484/django-best-way-to-add-javascript-to-custom-widgets)

But is not the same.

The original question asks how to add supporting javascript to a custom django widget, and the answer is to use `forms.Media`, but that solution does not work for me. My example is this:

The widget, when rendered in a form, creates a line which looks like (toy example) this:

```
<div id="some-generated-id">Text here</div>
```

Now, what I also want to add to the output is another line looking like this:

```
<script>
$('#some-generated-id').datetimepicker(some-generated-options)
</script>
```

The initial idea is that when the widget is rendered, both the `div` and `script` get rendered, but that does not work. The problem is that the structure of the `html` document looks like:

```
-body
    - my widget
    - my widget's javascript
-script
    -calls to static files (jQuery, datetimepicker,...)
```

At the time the widget's javascript code is loaded in the browser, jQuery and datetimepicker js files have not yet been loaded (they load at the end of the document).

I cannot do this using `Media`, since the options and id I generate are vital to the function. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: if code is wrapped in a ready event handler, it doesn't matter where the plugin files are being loaded within page

Comment: @charlietfl But the code wrapped in `$(document).ready()` does not run because jQuery is not yet loaded. I load all static files at the end of the document.

Comment: then you have to also load this code after jQuery...can't reference jQuery until it exists

Comment: @charlietfl That's my whole point. How can I do that nicely? The thing is that the javascript  code is part of the django custom widget.

Comment: I don't know what a django custom widget is so can't help much with that. Presumably it would have some sort of method to define library dependencies perhaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#order-of-assets):

> The order in which assets are inserted into the DOM is often important. For example, you may have a script that depends on jQuery. Therefore, combining Media objects attempts to preserve the relative order in which assets are defined in each Media class.

Consider this example:

```
class FooWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('foo.js',)

class BarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('bar.js',)

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField(widget=BarWidget)
    field2 = forms.CharField(widget=FooWidget)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now when you call `form.media`, the scripts will render like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/foo.js"></script>
```

Why does `bar.js` render before `foo.js`?  Because django renders them based on the order they were called on in the form, **not** the order that the classes were defined in.  If you want to change the order in this example, simply swap the position `field1` and `field2` in `SomeForm`.

How does this help you with jQuery?  You can render your jQuery CDN script via your custom widget:

```
class FooWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js', 'foo.js',)

class BarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js', 'bar.js',)
```

Now your `form.media` will look like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/foo.js"></script>
```

Notice how `/static/` wasn't appended to the jQuery CDN?  This is because the `.media` attribute checks whether the given filepaths contain `http` or `https`, and only appends your `STATIC_URL` setting to filepaths that are relative.

Also note that duplicate file names are automatically removed, so I would say it's good practice to include a `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js` at the beginning of *every* widget that requires it.  That way, no matter what order you render them in, the jQuery script will always appear before files that need it.

On a side note, I would be careful when including numbers in your filenames.  As Django 2.2 there appears to be a bug when trying to order the scripts.

For example:

```
class FooWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('foo1.js', 'foo2.js',)

class BarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('bar1.js', 'bar13.js',)

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField(widget=BarWidget)
    field2 = forms.CharField(widget=FooWidget)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bar1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/foo1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bar13.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/foo2.js"></script>
```

I've tried various combinations of names containing numbers, and I can't follow the logic, so I assume this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Since the JavaScript is an inline script, you will need to use a the native `DOMContentLoaded` event to wait for the jQuery to load.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        (function($) {
            $('#some-generated-id').datetimepicker(some-generated-options);
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Alternately, if you can put your code into an external script file, you can use the `defer` attribute of the `script` tag.

```
<script src="myfile.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes).

Comment: Its worth noting that `defer` is extremely unreliable, also it is a boolean attribute, so instead of `defer="defer">` you should just have `defer>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to **execute** some **plugin script on added div**. You need to **add class to your element** and associate a custom event to class. Which will execute your desire function or script.

To associate **custom event to dynamically added node**, please refer below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>adding javascript to custom widgets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="team">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container maxwidth">
                <button data-tab="tab1" class="active">AA<span></span></button>
            </div>

            <div class="maincontent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".active").click(function(){
            $(".maincontent").append("<div class='scroll'><h2>Hello</h2><div style='background:red; height:500px;'></div></div>")
            $(".maincontent").find(".scroll").trigger('dynload');
        });

        $('.container').on('dynload', '.scroll', function(){
            console.log("Append event fired");
            // Additinal Script resource you want to load for plugin
            $.getScript("Custom_Scrollbar.min.js") //script URL with abosolute path
            .done(function() {
                // Script loaded successfully calling of function           
                $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                // Give you error when script not loaded in browser
                console.log('Script file not loaded');
            })
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You should init JS as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var some-generated-options = {};
    $('#some-generated-id').datetimepicker(some-generated-options);
});
</script>
```

Like you I did own custom widget that look as:

```
class DaysInput(TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        result = super(DaysInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        return u"""
            %s
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('a.id_days').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('input#id_days').val($(e.currentTarget).attr('attr-value'));
                });
            });
            </script>
            <a href="#" class="id_days" attr-value='1'>1d</a>
            <a href="#" class="id_days" attr-value='2'>2d</a>
            <a href="#" class="id_days" attr-value='3'>3d</a>
        """ % result


class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    days = forms.IntegerField(widget=DaysInput())
```

Comment: But that does not work. Because the jquery call `$(document)` still appears right in the middle of the body of the document, not at the end, meaning it appears before jquery is loaded.

Comment: @5xum you should put your important JS libs into <head> section.

Comment: I disagree. I have, from multiple sources, heard that it's better to put the js scripts at the end (for quicker page loading).